# can i transfer my database from HeidiSQL to Mysql Workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench, heidisql

I have a database with few table in HeidiSQL, I would like to transfer it to MySQL Workbench. I used the SQL Export to export the selected database as Single.sql file. Then i used the import option in MySQL. Used import from self-contained file in MySQL workbench. The import was done, but I don't see any data.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand how [RDBMSes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) like MySQL are working. There is a server which holds the data and answers to requests by clients, and there are clients like HeidiSQL or MySQL Workbench. Clients never hold data by design. Their entire purpose is to communicate with a database server (running queries, manage it etc.).

Considering this you will see that your question is entirely wrong. There is no data you can move from one client to another. Simply use either client to connect to your server and it will have the data ready for you to work with.

Comment: then will i be able to make a local copy of the data. I don't want to work on the server data directly.

Comment: Depends on how you want to work on the data. If you need it like in a db server then you can set up a local server (that's very simple with MySQL, especially on Windows) and migrate the data using the WB migration wizard. If it's just about searching something or processing the data in a different app then a simple export might do the job (see Table Data Export in the schema tree context menu).